# How to get do loop in SAS to work with date values?

Tags: loops, date, if-statement, sas

I have a data set containing 4 years data (2014-2017).
I want to give every observation a period-variable containing E, E/F or F from an if-criteria.

I got it to work by repeating my code for every year in a data step:

data new;
    set old;

```
format period $10.;

if year=2014 then do;
    if start<'01feb2014'd and end<='01mar2014'd then period='E'; 
    else if start<'01feb2014'd and end>'01mar2014'd then period='E/F'; 
    else if start>='01feb2014'd then period='F';
end;
if year=2015 then do;
    if start<'01feb2015'd and end<='01mar2015'd then period='E'; 
    else if start<'01feb2015'd and end>'01mar2015'd then period='E/F'; 
    else if start>='01feb2015'd then period='F';
end;

if year=2016 then do;
    if start<'01feb2016'd and end<='01mar2016'd then period='E'; 
    else if start<'01feb2016'd and end>'01mar2016'd then period='E/F'; 
    else if start>='01feb2016'd then period='F';
end;
if year=2017 then do;
    if start<'01feb2017'd and end<='01mar2017'd then period='E'; 
    else if start<'01feb2017'd and end>'01mar2017'd then period='E/F'; 
    else if start>='01feb2017'd then period='F';
end;
```

run;

But I want to do the code smarter, by using af do loop.
I tried this:

data new;
    set old;

```
format period $10.;

do i=0 to 3;
    if year=(2014+i) then do;

        if start<'01feb(2014+i)'d and end<='01mar(2014+i)'d then period='E'; 
        else if start<'01feb(2014+i)'d and end>'01mar(2014+i)'d then period='E/F'; 
        else if start>='01feb(2014+i)'d then period='F';
    end;

end;
```

run;

But that doesn't give the right results for the years 2015-2017.

I also tried this:

data new;
    set old;

```
format period $10.;

do i=2014 to 2017;
    if year=(i) then do;

        if start<'01feb(i)'d and end<='01mar(i)'d then period='E'; 
        else if start<'01feb(i)'d and end>'01mar(i)'d then period='E/F'; 
        else if start>='01feb(i)'d then period='F';
    end;

end;
```

run;

But the code can't even run?

What an I missing??

Kind regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MDY(3,1, 2017);` to create a date from integers. You can also use the function `INTNX('month',dt,12,'END') + 1;` to add 12 month to a date `dt` and then reach the end of the month and add 1 to reach the starting of the next month.

So if I'm not wrong, the code below should work.

```
format period $10.;

do i=2014 to 2017;
    if year=(i) then do;

        if start<MDY(2,1, i) and end<=MDY(3,1, i) then period='E'; 
        else if start<MDY(2,1, i) and end>MDY(3,1, i) then period='E/F'; 
        else if start>=MDY(2,1, i) then period='F';
    end;

end;
```

Comment: This gives me what I want - and the right results. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you would need a DO loop for that data. The different years are on different observations.  You can use the `MDY()` function to build a date from separate month, day and year values.

```
data new;
  set old;
  length period $10;
  if start<mdy(2,1,year) and end<=mdy(3,1,year) then period='E'; 
  else if start<mdy(2,1,year) and end>mdy(3,1,year) then period='E/F'; 
  else if start>=mdy(2,1,year) then period='F'; 
  else period=' ';
run;
```

If the YEAR variable is not in your data and you want to replicate your data into separate observations for each of the years 2014 to 2017 then you could add a DO loop with an OUTPUT statement inside of it.

```
data new;
  set old;
  length year 8 period $10;
  do year=2014 to 2017;
    if start<mdy(2,1,year) and end<=mdy(3,1,year) then period='E'; 
    else if start<mdy(2,1,year) and end>mdy(3,1,year) then period='E/F'; 
    else if start>=mdy(2,1,year) then period='F'; 
    else period=' ';
    output;
  end;
run;
```

**P.S.** The `FORMAT` statement is used to attach special instructions for how to display the variable, but SAS does not need special instructions to display character variables. If you want to define a new variable before you start using it in your data step code you can use either the `LENGTH` or `ATTRIB` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just wanted to generate some code without so many replications.